# Beryllium Neutron Multiplier

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, experimental-technique, elements

We know that **Beryllium** is used in blankets of Fusion Systems because it is a *neutron multiplier*. I was wondering that if Beryllium is a neutron multiplier can it be used in the fission process(of nuclear reactors) to sustain a chain reaction?

Comment: Using https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp one can see that the (n,2n) reaction of Be-9 only kicks in above 1MeV neutron energy, and the cross section is less than 1 barn. Moderated fission reactors will not do anything unless the Be is part of the fuel, and even then the cross section isn't that great, needing a lot of Be.

Comment: Sort of related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208690/123208 but it talks about using beryllium as a neutron reflector (and a moderator), not a neutron moderator.